# Should I use a .class or element in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Currently, I use `<emb>` to stylize text, but should I turn `emb` into a class using a dot? I was checking `<span>` element where a class can be used so I wondered if I should try or, leave it. Would there be any benefit?

**HTML:**

```
This is some text

<emb>This is some styled text</emb>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
  emb {
       font-weight: 500;
       background: transparent;
       font-size: 18px
    }
</style>
```

I often use `<emb>` as needed to highlight parts of text.

Comment: Is `<emb>` a standard HTML element? IMO, you should try to use the "rightest" element for each use, which in this case could be `<em>` or `<i>` or `<b>` for example. Whether to select elements by tag name or class is a personal preference.

Comment: There is no HTML `emb` element, so, no, you should not use it if you wish to have valid HTML documents. There is no `emp` element either, @Julia. Perhaps you're thinking of `em`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey: oops, that is embarrasing. Yes I am.

Comment: If i understand you can use <mark> to highlight parts of text.

Comment: I have `<emb>` in the CSS I pasted. It seems to working. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`emb` is not an existing, valid HTML tag and you should not be using it in 'pure' HTML/CSS systems.

There are several HTML tags that enable you to emphasise or mark text of special relevance.

They each have slightly different meanings/uses and you need to look up the meaning of each to make sure you are using them correctly (such tags include `em, i, strong, mark`).

However, they are not intended for general purpose styling for which you should use an 'ordinary' CSS class in an element with a tag which otherwise has no great semantic inference of its own (such as `span` as you mention).

Comment: I have defined `emb` inside `<style>`. How come nobody noticed the CSS I pasted? When I use `emb` its working just fine as expected.

Comment: It is not legal HTML. You haven't defined a custom tag called emb.

Comment: There are ways of defining custom elements but there are rules, including naming conventions and how to register them. See for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements As it stands, putting your code through a validator gives this sort of error: Error: Element emb not allowed as child of element body in this context.

Comment: I see. But why does it work without any problems when I use it `<emb>Some Text</emb>` ?

Comment: It works without any problems because browsers are very forgiving! They do their best to render whatever they see.

Comment: Okay, I see. I needed to use it in a markdown. I don't want to customize `em, i, strong` stuff with CSS. Are you suggesting to use a class `.emb` with `<span>` tag?. Would that be the only way?